# Installation of Magento2 stuck at 0% in windows

Tags: magento2

I am trying to install `Magento 2.2.8` in my windows 10 using xampp, but the installation is stuck at 0% and no errors are shown in console. Can anyone guide me how can i install it

Comment: try again your installation and make sure all hardware and software requirements are met

Comment: also make sure installation directories are not read only

Answer (score 0):

Magento's official stance is they [do not support Magento 2 natively on Windows](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html#operating-systems-linux-x86-64) (or Mac). They recommend using the [Windows' Subsystem for Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10), or a virtual machine solution like Docker or Vagrant.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue and i solved by installing via cammand line in  windows 10

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://localhost/mag234/" --db-host="localhost" --db-name="mag234" --db-user="root" --admin-firstname="admin" --admin-lastname="admin" --admin-email="admin@admin.com" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin123" --language="en_US" --currency="INR" --timezone="America/Chicago" --use-rewrites="1" --backend-frontname="admin"
```

use your DB name